# Blender 2.83.2 crashing plasmashell 5.19.3 Arch linux

Tags: linux

I'm running into a weird bug here and I can't find other resources. I installed Blender with pacman and it opens and runs smoothly, then randomly something will cause it freeze the entire plasma session.

I am running blender on a 32 gb Dell Latitude e7270 without graphic card integration.

Blender is v 2.83.2
Plasma is plasmashell 5.19.3

Here's a pastebin of the last `blender --debug-all` when I was playing around with camera angles, and moving the default box around:
https://pastebin.com/67G8qnEb

The last lines before freezing the session were

```
[SCScene :: View Layer]: deg_evaluate_copy_on_write on OBCamera (0x7fe68570f438)
[SCScene :: View Layer]: BKE_object_eval_local_transform on OBCamera (0x7fe68570f438)
[SCScene :: View Layer]: BKE_object_eval_transform_final on OBCamera (0x7fe68570f438)
Depsgraph updated in 0.000129 seconds.
Depsgraph evaluation FPS: 3.166230
UI_menutype_draw: opening menu "TOPBAR_MT_editor_menus"
```

I still had plenty of memory left. The interface for blender seemed to be stuck jittering between two positions in the camera transform.

Is anyone else facing blender issues?

Can I debug and get it running? I have a surface pro laptop that runs it smoothly that has no gpu and only 8gb of memory (also running arch with plasma 5.19.3)

Comment: I have freeze issue ,
i m using Arcolinux (arch based)
playing with default cube about 15 mins , blender freeze my whole OS only mouse can move on screen graphics are glitched then i have to hard reboot.
my specs are i5 8400
8gb ram
intel uhd 630 Os Arcolinux (DE plasama)
Kernel 5.7.9-arch1-1 someone also have issue here is link https://developer.blender.org/T77875

Comment: This sounds more likely to be a GPU driver problem that Blender is triggering in some way. I found [this page listing a number of known intel driver problems](https://linuxreviews.org/Linux_Kernel_5.5_Will_Not_Fix_The_Frequent_Intel_GPU_Hangs_In_Recent_Kernels), do any of them seem applicable? (If you can ssh into the machine after the crash, you might check the output of `dmesg`, or on the next boot, check the output of `journalctl -k -b -1`)